# Using docker command without root with user namespace mapping: permission error

Tags: docker

I want to build a docker image using `docker build` without root privileges.

I followed the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/) to setup user namespace remapping, but when I run `docker image ls` (or `docker build -t myapp .` or `docker run hello-world`) the following error is shown:

```
permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/images/json": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

Following the instructions in the section [Enable userns-remap on the daemon](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/#enable-userns-remap-on-the-daemon), I have configured `"userns-remap": "default"` in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` as well as created ranges for this user in `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid`.

The docker daemon is running, started through systemd, and the log files show that namespacing is enabled with the `dockremap` user:

```
level=info msg="User namespaces: ID ranges will be mapped to subuid/subgid ranges of: dockremap"
level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
level=warning msg="Not using native diff for overlay2, this may cause degraded performance for building images: kernel has CONFIG_OVERLAY_FS_REDIRECT_DIR enabled" storage-driver=overlay2
level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=659604f9ee graphdriver=overlay2 version=24.0.2
level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
Started Docker Application Container Engine.
```

However, when I now as my normal user run the docker command, this results in the permission error shown above.

The permissions for the file mentioned in the error:

```
0 srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Jul 14 13:35 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Did I misunderstand the instructions and the docker command has to be run by the `dockremap` user? However, the following does not output anything: `sudo su dockremap -c "docker image ls"`. Also I cannot login as the `dockremap` user, even after setting a password for it.

So my question is: What should I expect after following the setup from the documentation, and how can I then use the `docker` command without root, especially to build an image?